# Why my Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate doesn't have MPI Cluster Debugger?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, compiler-construction, mpi

As this article(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ee441265.aspx#BKMK_debugMany) says: when we create a MS-MPI application in Visual Studio(pro or higher), we can use MPI Cluster Debugger to debug our parallel program, but when I open the list "Debugger to launch" and there are no debugger named "MPI Cluster Debugger", I want to know why and how to get it in my VS then?

Comment: Did you read the documentation? It's for Visual Studio 2010.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why my Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate doesn't have MPI Cluster Debugger?

Because it's in Visual Studio 2010 [not Visual Studio 2013](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/3075084-bring-back-the-mpi-cluster-debugger). From [the page you linked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ee441265.aspx):

> ## Walkthrough: Launching the MPI Cluster Debugger in Visual Studio 2010
>
> ### Visual Studio 2010

[The download page is clear as well](http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=21705):

> File Name:
> SOADebugger_VS2010.msi
> Date Published:
> 18/01/2011
> File Size:
> 688 KB

Comment: oh...God this is a really stupid question!! thanks anyway T.T